# How I get URL of a customer record in suitetalk by passing recordType and internalId

Tags: suitetalk

I am getting the customer records by passing the saved search script id and some filters in CustomerSearchAdvanced, but I want URL of each record also

example- recordType customer and internalId is 3645

URL is --  https://------.app.netsuite.com/app/common/entity/custjob.nl?id=3645

Comment: What's wrong with the example that you provide? It seems like you've already figured this out.

Comment: What is the alternate of resolveRecord(type, id) of suitescript 2.0 in suitetalk, how i can get the record url in suitetalk.

Comment: above URL just an example that I have to get in suitetalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My organization chose to just hard-code the URLs for each record type and then append the internal id. Fortunately, all record families share a single URL that resolves to the specific record type URL based on the internal id. Here is an example of what I mean:

`"/app/accounting/transactions/transaction.nl?id=1234567"`

This URL format can be used for all transactions. Assuming that record 1234567 is a sales order, this resolves to:

`"/app/accounting/transactions/salesord.nl?id=1234567"`

If record 1234567 is an estimate, then this will resolve to:

`"/app/accounting/transactions/estimate.nl?id=1234567"`

Therefore, you will not have to hard-code URLs for each record type, just each record family. Here are some other family URLs:

`"/app/common/entity/entity.nl?id="`
`"/app/common/item/item.nl?id="`